# jQuery ajax submit validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin and then submit my form via ajax, but I'm missing something. Anybody have any insight?

```
$('#theForm').validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    invalidHandler: function () {
        $('#message').addClass('error').html('Please fill out all necessary fields.').slideDown();
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $('#message').removeClass('error').html('Saving info.').slideDown();
        $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), function () {
            $('#message').removeClass('error').html('Saving complete.').slideUp(3500);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing

> $(form).serialize()

to the second parameter of $.post which should be passed key/value pairs in the form of

> { name: "John", time: "2pm" }

where as serialize() returns a query string. Try using serializeArray() which returns a JSON data structure. If that doesn't work you might need to manually retrieve each value from the form and pass them to $.post as key/value pairs.

Comment: $.post() can take a query string as the second parameter. Example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/: 

$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());

This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For submit form via AJAX, you should consider [Malsup's Form Plugins](http://malsup.com/jquery/form). It provide a better way to handle various form field's type. To make it work with jQuery validation plugins, see [this example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html).